# 18.10 have to press twice "winkey+L" to lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, 18.10

Since I upgraded from 18.04 to 18.10 I have to press twice "winkey+l" to lock the screen.

Lot of other problems with 18.10, not a great release :(

Comment: I've got the same problem. It was working fine but broke in the last day or so.

Comment: I can top this. After locking the screen through either winkey+L or closing the lid and later reopening, screen content remains visible, flickers, and top-right panel items can still be clicked (but the opened submenu is unresponsive). Only locking the screen by waiting long enough (inactivity) actually works as expected. I would recommend not to upgrade to 18.10.

Comment: I experience an identical behavior as described by Ludwig Schulze

Comment: The developers did not intend this behavior. Please check launchpad.net to see if the bug has already been reported. If so, subscribe. If not, please report it.

Comment: Fixed with the new patch 11/05